# plot is not shown when I call plt.show() in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm currently learning python and i saw this code in a book but it's not working for me. it's about dynamic visualization of rolling a die:

```
from matplotlib import animation
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random
import seaborn as sns


def update(frame_number, rolls, faces, frequencies):
    for i in range(rolls):
        frequencies[random.randrange(1, 7) - 1] += 1
    plt.cla()
    axes = sns.barplot(faces, frequencies, palette='bright')
    axes.set_title(f'Die Frequencies for {sum(frequencies):,} Rolls')
    axes.set(xlabel='Die Value', ylabel='Frequency')
    axes.set_ylim(top=max(frequencies) * 1.10)
    for bar, frequency in zip(axes.patches, frequencies):
        text_x = bar.get_x() + bar.get_width() / 2.0
        text_y = bar.get_height()
        text = f'{frequency:,}\n{frequency / sum(frequencies):.3%}'
        axes.text(text_x, text_y, text, ha='center', va='bottom')


number_of_frames = 10000  
rolls_per_frame = 600
sns.set_style('whitegrid')
figure = plt.figure('Rolling a Six-Sided Die')
values = list(range(1, 7))
frequencies = [0] * 6

die_animation = animation.FuncAnimation(figure, update, repeat=False, frames=number_of_frames, interval=33,
                                        fargs=(rolls_per_frame, values, frequencies))
plt.show()
```

after running the script nothing happens.
Note that matplotlib and seaborn are working correctly in my system. I used them for static visualization beforehand.

[image]

There is no problem with this code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import random
import seaborn as sns

rolls = [random.randrange(1, 7) for i in range(600)]

values, frequencies = np.unique(rolls, return_counts=True)

title = f'Rolling a six-sided die {len(rolls):,} Times'
sns.set_style('whitegrid')
axes = sns.barplot(x=values, y=frequencies, palette='bright')
axes.set_title(title)
axes.set(xlabel='Die value', ylabel='Frequency')

axes.set_ylim(top=max(frequencies) * 1.10)

for bar, frequency in zip(axes.patches, frequencies):
    text_x = bar.get_x() + bar.get_width() / 2.0
    text_y = bar.get_height()
    text = f'{frequency:,}\n{frequency / len(rolls):.3%}'
    axes.text(text_x, text_y, text, fontsize=11, ha='center', va='bottom')

plt.show()
```

[image]

I don't know why plot is not shown in the first code.

Comment: Try with blit=True as a parameter

Comment: What is animation?

Comment: when i ran the code its working fine . die frequencies for roll is updating and bars also changing what exactly u got stuck with?

Comment: nothing happens when i run this code. I uploaded the screenshot

Comment: I used blit=True as a parameter but the problem is not solved. no plot is shown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the problem is with pycharm pro version. it's not working in pro version but it works in community version.
thanks to Adhun Thalekkara for noticing that.
I used the cmd to run the code and it worked correctly for me.

Answer (score 1):

just imported animation from matplotlib and your code was running pretty fine

```
from matplotlib import animation
```

[image]

Comment: I already imported it but when I copied the script here, the first line left.
I edited the code now.

Comment: got any errors or anything?? same code works fine for me. Have you tried any sample plots in order to ensure your matplotlib library works fine?

Comment: I uploaded the output screenshot in the post. no error occurs.

Comment: Try to plot  any sample plot using matplotlib

Comment: and what is the problem you facing excatly?

Comment: as you see, the plot of the first code is not shown. but there is no problem in the second code.
I don't know why it's not working in the first code that i wrote on top of the post

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219396/discussion-between-adhun-thalekkara-and-amir).